# Compare equality of a string against a set of strings

Tags: r, dataframe

I am used to do in SQL to enumerate possiblities for a string.

something like this:

```
select * from  s1b where Phases in ('Phase 2', 'Phase 3','Phase 4', 'Phase 2|Phase 3')
```

I can not use sqldf because my data.frame has posix dates and those would get corupted. So I have to use native R methods.

How can I do comparison of a data.frame column against a set of  multiple strings without complicated OR code like this

```
s1btest<-subset(s1b,s1b$Phases=='Phase 2'|s1b$Phases=='Phase 3'| more conditions here)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `%in%` operator.

```
subset(s1b, Phases %in% c("Phase 2", "Phase 3"))
```